# Is this type of Type Punning Legal and Safe?

Tags: c++, unions, type-punning

I'm in the process of rolling my own struct to represent colors, and this is what I came up with:

```
struct Color {
    typedef uint8_t color_t;

    union {
        struct {
            color_t red, green, blue, alpha;
        };
        struct {
            color_t x, y, z, w;
        }
        std::array<color_t, 4> _data;
    };

    /*...*/
};
```

The idea is to simplify the act of writing indexing code. Like, for example, the `operator[]` code is written like this:

```
//I haven't written bounds-checking yet.
constexpr color_t & operator[](size_t i) {
    return _data[i];
}

constexpr color_t operator[](size_t i) const {
    return _data[i];
}
```

My understanding is that this should be safe (and indeed, this code compiles and runs as I expect it to) but am I actually correct in this assumption, or am I potentially risking Undefined Behavior by writing my code like this?

Comment: I believe I saw several questions about this, during the past days (maybe someone will find a duplicate, for it, because I am too lazy). You would be much safer if, instead of `union`, you would have references to elements of the array.

Comment: The source file of that structure will probably be quite small, so why don't you simply write out larger code instead of using a union (which one should avoid whenever possible)? Also, might I ask why you define operator[] on it? The order of the channels is not automatically given, which means that nobody is responsible to maintain it like that. If you need to write a color in some file, give that responsibility either to the color structure itself or to the image class that writes it, but then use  code that makes the order clear, like `<< red << green << blue`.

Comment: Aside: you don't need to implement bounds checking yourself, just use [`std::array::at()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/at)

Comment: It'll probably be _safe_ as long as you stick to compilers which 1) allow type punning through unions, and 2) use the same layout for `struct { T a, b, c, d; };` as they do for `std::array<T, 4> abcd;`.  This doesn't, however, mean it'll be a good idea, or that it isn't UB; it just means that it's such a common form of UB that compilers are designed to accomodate it.  It could easily cause problems if you run into a compiler which doesn't allow it.

Answer (score 3):

Reading from a member of a union that is not active is undefined behaviour.

Only one member of a union can be active at a time.

Layout compatibility of prefixes is an exception, but arrays are not layout compatible with any `struct`
with multiple members under the standard.

It may be possible to produce a legal efficient `operator[](size_t)`, but not via `union`.

Comment: If `uint8_t` is a character type, is there any reason that the rule which allows PODS of any type to be read and written via character pointers would not be applicable to access through the array?